# Can we always pick an integer power of $e^{i \theta}$ such that its difference with $1$ has rational argument?

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $z = e^{i\theta}, \theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, does there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$1 - z^n  = re^{2 \pi i \tau}$$

for some $\tau \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Naturally, this exists if $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. However, does this hold for any $\theta$?

Although this question appears quite simple, I have no idea how I would approach it, and I suspect that its proof or disproof would be very difficult.

Link to [*motivation*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452775/does-this-property-of-certain-fields-have-a-better-description?noredirect=1#comment9325845_4452775) (it may appear entirely unrelated (it almost is); I wish to show that $\mathbb{C}$ has a certain property that I defined on fields with the addition of some analysis.)

Comment: Whether a question is simple or complicated doesn't matter in terms of quality.  What matters is askers providing sufficient context.  Motivation for asking it?  Source of question? Effort?  You provide little context.

Comment: @amWhy Motivation -- see the last question I asked on MSE. It's difficult to explain, and would not appear relevant. (And this question is apparently still interesting enough that two others upvoted it without knowing this motivation.) Source of question, myself. Effort -- I would put it in if I thought I could make any meaningful progress. As I say, I have no idea how to start. If you can suggest even one fruitful idea, I'd be happy to try to work on it myself.

Comment: Effort is the least of my concerns.  Is this a repeat of your former question?  I'm not about to chase down your profile to find a post, and you should not expect other users to do so either.  At the very least, provide a direct link to "the last question" you asked on math.se.

Comment: I think $\theta = \sqrt{2}$, or any irrational number that is linearly independent to $\pi$ should be a counter-example.

Comment: Yes, for this type of questions finding a counterexample should be the first thing that should come to mind.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I agree it seems unlikely this holds (could $\theta$ rational not be a counterexample too?). If this was $z^n$, it would be easy, but since this is $1-z^n$, determining whether the resulting expression must have irrational argument seems to become very difficult -- to me, it seemed intractable so I did not even mention this in the post as an approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, on basis of set cardinalities. The possible pairings of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\tau \in \mathbb{Q}$ are countable. Each of those equations has at most $n$ solutions for $z$, so a finite count. So the set of $\theta$ where the problem has any solution is countable. $[0, 2\pi] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, so it contains many values of $\theta$ with no solution.

Answer (score 3):

$\arg (1-z^n)=n\theta/2-\pi/2=2\pi \tau+2k\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ so $\theta=\frac{4\pi (\tau+k+1/4)}{n}$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$

Comment: I don't follow the first equality, and there may be a slight error. Let $z=i, n=1$. The argument of $1-i$ is $\frac{-\pi}{4}$.

Comment: $1-\cos n\theta-i\sin n\theta=2\sin^2n\theta/2-2i\sin n\theta/2  \cos n\theta/2=-2i\sin n\theta/2(\cos n\theta/2+i\sin n\theta/2=2\sin n\theta/2e^{i(n\theta-\pi/2)}$, so you are right, we actually get $n\theta/2-\pi/2$ but the result still holds

Comment: Yes, the result holds. That is very neat manipulation. Thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help